# Is it possible to replace blank cells in a Google Query with text?

Tags: google-query-language

I have built a table that uses SUM, COUNT, AVG using Google Query. It has a lot of blank cells because the data is missing. I want to see "N/A" in the blank cells. Is it possible to do this? Considering the query is aggregating numerical data and would spit out an error if I mixed data types?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(QUERY(your_query_here)=""; "N/A"; QUERY(your_query_here)))
```